# выравнивание блока по центру

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, что-то всю голову сломал, без текста получается все ровно, но если добавить текст в блок, то ерунда полная.
Имеется следующая HTML-разметка страницы и изображение logo.gif:

```
<body>
  <div>SEO-продвижение и оптимизация сайтов</div>
</body>
```

Необходимо с помощью каскадных таблиц стилей сделать, чтобы этот блок (div) находился по центру окна браузера, имел фиксированный размер 300×300px, изображение (logo.gif) было выровнено по центру блока, а текст в блоке — по левому краю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url("some.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<div class = "centered">
    <div class = "text">SEO-продвижение и оптимизация сайтов</div>
</div>
```

Если я правильно понял задачу, возможно так вы ее решите

Comment: background-position: center; вот этого мне не хватило чтобы решить самому) спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Из того что вы описали, могу посоветовать сделать  `<div aligh="center">`, это выровняет по центру. Для изображения добавить тоже `aligh="center"`.  А с помощью CSS и `width`,`height` указать размеры.

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, это что-то типа такого

```css
.is_block {
 position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
  width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
 background: #bfbfbf;
}

.text {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="is_block">
  <div class="text">
    Тут текст
  </div> 
  <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637425/v637425814/56e4f/bpfrax9-1cw.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/squh7y4j